# how may I remove elements in a string vector by elements in another string vector

Tags: r, set-difference

```
setdiff(c("a","c"),c("a","b","c","d"))
 #character(0)
```

This code is supposed to return a vector of c("b","d"), what's wrong with it?

Comment: other way around... `setdiff(c("a","b","c","d"), c("a", "c"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setdiff` is asymmetric, as the help page warns about (though subtly).

This works as you expect,

```
> setdiff(c("a","b","c","d"),c("a","c"))
[1] "b" "d"
```

A simple function works either way,

```
setdiff2 <- function(x,y){
  d1 <- setdiff(x,y)
  d2 <- setdiff(y,x)
  if(length(d2) > length(d1))
    return(d2)
  else
    return(d1)
}

> setdiff2(c("a","c"), c("a","b","c","d"))
[1] "b" "d"
```

Comment: `setdiff2` looks highly counter-intuitive to me and is definitively not symmetric: `setdiff2(c('a','b'),c('b','c'))` returns `'a'` while swapping the arguments, i.e., `setdiff2(c('b','c'),c('a','b'))`, gives us `'c'`.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is a very naive function that is only intuitive in some cases but not others. I think setdiff is asymmetric because it should be!